# Getting error "Failed to instantiate module app due to unknown provider" with my custom provider

Tags: angularjs

Trying to create custom provider and use it during app config. During configuration phase getting an error "Failed to instantiate module app due to unknown provider 'configRoutesProvider'".
Provider code:

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app-routing', [])
        .provider('configRoutesProvider', function () {

            this.$get = ['$http', getRoutesProvider];

            function getRoutesProvider($http) {
                return {
                    getRoutes: function ($http) {
                        return $http.get('https://localhost:44311/api/account/routes').then(function (results) {
                            return results;
                        });
                    }
                };
            }
        });
}).call(this);
```

In app.js code get a reference to the 'app-routing' module:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app',
            [
                'ngRoute',              // routing
                'LocalStorageModule',   // local storage

                'app-routing'
            ]);


        app.run();
})();
```

And in config.js when trying to reference the provider get the above error:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 'configRoutesProvider', routeConfigurator]);
    function routeConfigurator($routeProvider, configRoutesProvider) {
        var routes = configRoutesProvider.getRoutes();
        routes.forEach(function (r) {
            $routeProvider.when(r.href, {
                controller: r.controller,
                templateUrl: r.templateUrl
            });
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });

    }
```

In index.html the order of scripts registration is following:

```
<script src="app/routesProvider.js"></script>
<!-- Load app main script -->
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/config.js"></script>
```

Can't understand what I miss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In angular, providers doesn't have the `provider` part on its name, so the idea is to have:

```
angular.module('foo').provider('configRoutes', function() { });
```

and not:

```
angular.module('foo').provider('configRoutesProvider', function() { });
```

But when you inject it on a config, you have to put it:

```
angular.module('foo').config(function(configRoutesProvider) { });
```

So, in your example, remove the `provider` part on the definition.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It's working. I'm very new to AngularJS and I didn't see this in documentation.

Comment: Wow.  That is painful.  So just to change a service to a provider I have to hunt down all the times I inject that service?  Ugh.

Comment: Great answer! This is totally unintuitive though - does anyone have a link for where this appears in the documentation?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and assume this is the same for Services

Answer (score -1):

File : **route.js**

```
var appRoutes = angular.module('appRoutes',['ngRoute'])
appRoutes.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){  
$routeProvider
.when('/',{
   templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/home.html'
})
.when('/about',{
   templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/about.html'
})
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
console.log('Testing routes routes...');
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false,
});
});
```

Its-Works.
It is another way to define the routes in route.js file.
Here i give the path properly and use the $routeProvider , $locationPRovider , ngroute